# Shell to add contents of file in single cell of csv

Tags: linux, shell, csv

I have a scenario to put all the file contents in single cell of csv file.
File Contents

```
this is sample file
and contents should go
to single cell
```

i tried with for loop but the contents are going to every cell.

Comment: Did you try to write a program (in which language) or did you try to do something in the shell command line? Can you add the program or command line that you have tried to your question?

Comment: So, just remove all line breaks and commas (or whatever your column separator is) and then everything is one cell?

Answer (score 0):

I have opened Excel, and I have put the multiline text in cell A1. Then I've saved it as a CSV file, it looks as follows:

```
"this is sample file
and contents should go
to single cell"
```

So, just put everything between double quotes and you have it.

I have then copied the content of cell A1 to B2 and saved again, this time it looked like this:

```
"this is sample file
and contents should go
to single cell";
;"this is sample file
and contents should go
to single cell"
```

Apparently, using the semi-colon gives you the opportunity to separate cells (careful, this might be a comma, depending on locale settings, on your computer).